# Deriving the Bending Energy equation for Eulers Elastica

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

In many (all?) papers regarding elastic curves the bending energy for the elastica is given by $$B[\gamma] = \int_{\gamma} \kappa^2(s)ds$$ where $\gamma$ denotes a planar curve of fixed length and clamped endpoints. Here $s$ denotes the arc length of the curve and $\kappa$ is the (signed) curvature.

I want to know where this equation comes from and how it is derived. Here is one of the papers I am reading: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05890.pdf In all of the material I have found the above bending energy is given as a definition and no motivation for it is given. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can really do some kind of derivation of this energy. It should model the bending energy of thin elastic rods. The idea is the following: The more the rod is bend, the more curvature there should be, i.e. $B$ should be large. If you just follow this purely physical idea it is in my opinion not clear why you shouldn't model your bending energy for example by $\int \kappa^p\, ds$.

Comment: @Ozera Was it really necessary to define $\gamma$ to be planar?

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh: yes, otherwise the energy due to torsion will add (re. to my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, you are missing some physical constants in your formula: you should say that the 
elastic energy is proportional to the integral of the squared curvature.

To derive that, take a segment of a bent thin beam  whose barycentric axis describes
the given curve.
Take an infinitesimal sector $ds=Rd\alpha$ of the beam, with curvature radius $=R$, and compute the strain of a small fiber of the beam
at distance $x$ from the barycentric axis: you will find that is $\epsilon=((R+x)d\alpha-Rd\alpha)/(Rd\alpha)=x/R)$.
The corresponding elastic energy per volume will be $1/2E*(x/R)^2$, which integrated all over the cross section will give $1/2EI_y/R^2ds$.

*Brief explanation*

Since you asked for that I am trying to give some hint on how to start and understand the subject.
Then have a look [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_%28structure%29) and [at this other one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory) for a better assessment.

[image: Bending_1]

If you take a thin beam and imagine to cut a piece out of it at $s$ and $s+ds$, the coehesion forces acting on each small area
of the cross section ,i.e. the stress $\sigma$ (thus actually a pressure distribution), will translate into a resultant normal force $N$ (tension), 
tangential force $T$ (shear) and a moment of them $M$ (bending moment). We omit here the other possible resultant which is torque.
These resultants, taken on both sides shall equilibrate with the external forces (load $ Fds$ and the reactions at the support points).

The "slender beams" approximation (that is for beams relatively thin compared to the length) says that , when laterally loaded, 
the deformation is mainly due to the moment: we can approximate the cohesion forces with a triangular distribution in the plane of
bending, with negligible resulting tension and shear.  The strain $\epsilon=\Delta l /l$ of each elementary axial fiber will have the same triangular
distribution. The deformation of the $ds$ sector will result in a circular "wedge" with radius $R$ corresponding to the curvature.

The strain $\epsilon$ as told equals $x/R$, the stress $\sigma$ is linearly related to it by the [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus), the elastic energy per volume
of each elementary fiber will be $1/2\sigma \epsilon$, the total is thus $1/2\sigma \epsilon dl dA=1/2E x^2/R^2 dl(x) dA(x)$.
Summing over the cross section will give $1/2EI_y/R^2ds$.

Comment: 1) Does "elastic energy" mean the same thing as "bending energy" here? 2) I've never learned what strain means, but that I can google and then I assume i'll be able to understand what you've written. Thanks!

Comment: @Ozera: 1) yes, elastic energy related to the bending deformation (there are or might be other components: pure tension, shear)  2) [strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_%28mechanics%29#Engineering_strain) is $\Delta l/l$

Comment: Thank you for that link regarding strain. It has helped a lot. Could you also explain how you obtained the $\frac{1}{2}E \cdot (\frac{x}{R})^2 ds$ and what $E$ denotes?

Comment: @Ozera: E is the [tensile elasticity modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus). Deformation and stress of an elastic body (and beams and plates in particular) constitute the starting basis for engineering study, and not easy to summarize here. I'll try to add a sketch and suggest some links to elementary introductive exposition.

Comment: Your first link does not contain a URL

Comment: @Ozera: sorry, links added